# How to modify instance value without using a function?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class:

```
class WeaponItems {

var name: String
var index: Int
var price: Int
var weaponPower: Int = 0
var attackSpeed: Double = 0
var criticalChance: Double = 0
var criticalDamage: Double = 0

init(name: String, index: Int, price: Int){
    self.name = name
    self.index = index
    self.price = price
}

var weaponBlade = WeaponItems(name: "Weapon Blade", index: 0, price: 300)
weaponBlade.weaponPower = 15
// Error: expected declaration

var swiftShooter = WeaponItems(name: "Swift Shooter", index: 1, price: 300)
swiftShooter.attackSpeed = 0.2
// Error: expected declaration

var minionsFoot = WeaponItems(name: "Minions Foot", index: 3, price: 300)
minionsFoot.criticalChance = 0.1
minionsFoot.criticalDamage = 0.1
// Error: expected declaration

}
```

I need to set `weaponPower` `attackSpeed` ... for each item, I got an error doing it this way.

I found answers saying you have to use a function to modify instances' values, but I feel that makes the code complicated, how do I set the value of it otherwise?

The concern of using a function is it'll separate the instance-creating and value-setting process, making the code harder to maintain.

Comment: Why don't you just extend the init to include all the variables?

Comment: @Z.Hung how should I do that?

Comment: @BrightFuture you already have name,index and price. So maybe add the rest (like weaponPower,attackspeed,critchance and critdmg). So when you declare the var for the weapons you can include all the stats in the brackets

Comment: @Z.Hung if you mean why don't I put other all the values in the initializer, that's because in my project there are some more values, if I put all of them inside, each time I create new instance, I'll have to type in a lot, so I set some values to be default, then modify each items' unique value

Comment: Why are `weaponBlade` etc *instance* properties of `WeaponItems`?

Comment: @MartinR so I can create an instance of `weaponItems` in my view controller, then access them like `weaponItemInstance.weaponBlade`

Comment: @MartinR any way I need to access these values in view controller, that's the only method I know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to have default property values, which you would also like the opportunity to customise when creating an instance, then I would recommend using [default parameter values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166) in your initialiser. This will allow you to create a new instance of your `WeaponItems` class with the *actual* property values known at initialisation, rather than some default values which you then change immediately after.

I also strongly agree [with Luca D'Alberti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39385763/2976878) – there is no need for your 'preset weapons' to be instance properties. As they don't rely on any instance state, or are unique to a given instance – they should be `static`.

For example:

```
class Weapon {

    static var blade : Weapon {
        return Weapon(name: "Blade", index: 0, price: 300, power: 15)
    }

    static var swiftShooter : Weapon {
        return Weapon(name: "Swift Shooter", index: 1, price: 300, attackSpeed: 0.2)
    }

    static var minionsFoot : Weapon {
        return Weapon(name: "Minions Foot", index: 3, price: 300, criticalChance: 0.1, criticalDamage: 0.1)
    }

    var name: String
    var index: Int
    var price: Int
    var power: Int
    var attackSpeed: Double
    var criticalChance: Double
    var criticalDamage: Double

    init(name: String, index: Int, price: Int,
         power: Int = 0, attackSpeed: Double = 0,
         criticalChance: Double = 0, criticalDamage: Double = 0) {

        self.name = name
        self.index = index
        self.price = price
        self.power = power
        self.attackSpeed = attackSpeed
        self.criticalChance = criticalChance
        self.criticalDamage = criticalDamage
    }
}
```

```
let blade = Weapon.blade
let swiftShooter : Weapon = .swiftShooter
```

Comment: Great answer! The default parameter values is so cool, it shortened my code by 2/3; you are right about the type properties, or else the logic of this class would be a mess.

Answer (score 3):

you should add properties for all the weaponItems in the class

then your class implementation should look like this

```
class WeaponItems {

    var name: String
    var index: Int
    var price: Int
    var weaponPower: Int = 0
    var attackSpeed: Double = 0
    var criticalChance: Double = 0
    var criticalDamage: Double = 0

    var weaponBlade:WeaponItems{

        get {
            let tempWeaponBlade = WeaponItems(name: "Weapon Blade", index: 0, price: 300)
            tempWeaponBlade.weaponPower = 15
            return tempWeaponBlade
        }
    }

    var swiftShooter:WeaponItems{

        get {
            let tempSwiftShooter = WeaponItems(name: "Swift Shooter", index: 1, price: 300)
            tempSwiftShooter.attackSpeed = 0.2
            return tempSwiftShooter
        }
    }

    var minionsFoot:WeaponItems{

        get {
            let tempMinionsFoot = WeaponItems(name: "Minions Foot", index: 3, price: 300)
            tempMinionsFoot.criticalChance = 0.1
            tempMinionsFoot.criticalDamage = 0.1
            return tempMinionsFoot 
        }
    }


    init(name: String, index: Int, price: Int){
        self.name = name
        self.index = index
        self.price = price
    }

}
```

Comment: Why have you made the properties optional, when they return non-optional values? You also don't need the explicit `get { }`

Comment: Nice answer, I tried it and it works. 2 suggestions tho: 1. the instances don't have to be optional; 2. the `get {}` can be simplified as it's get only

Comment: @Hamish using get {  } in  a property declaration that only returns a value is for clarity purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, if the code would compile, to use your pre-created `weaponBlade`, you have to create two `WeaponItems` instances as below:

```
let balde = WeaponItems(name: "", index: 0, price: 0).weaponBlade
```

That's not the best solution, even because in your case doesn't compile at all (you can read the comment by @gnasher729 to understand why).

What I suggest you is to create static instances of them

```
extension WeaponItems {
    static var Blade: WeaponItems {
        get {
            let blade = WeaponItems(name: "The name", index: 1, price: 300)
            blade.weaponPower = 15
            return blade
        }
    }
}
```

And you can now use the blade by typing `WeaponItems.Blade`, or if it the type is easily inferred as below:

```
let blade: WeaponItems = .Blade
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but for now I think I'll just stick with @Prathamesh's code, as it's more suited to my level, would definitely put some thoughts in your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using like below code.

```
lazy var weaponBlade:WeaponItems = {

        let _weaponBlade = WeaponItems(name: "Weapon Blade", index: 0, price: 300)
        _weaponBlade.weaponPower = 15
        return _weaponBlade
    }()
```

Please refer this [link](http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/) to know more about lazy variable.